# Why is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I know that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous  on $(0,1)$ but why is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Do you know the basic properties of uniformly continuous functions? For example, they map bounded sets into bounded sets., and $(0,1)$ is mapped to $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: Intuitively, when you approach $0$, the slope goes to infinity so that you require larger and larger $\epsilon$ for a given $\delta$.

Answer (score 9):

No matter which $\delta>0$ you choose, you can make $|\frac1x-\frac1{x+\delta}|$ arbitarily large by picking $x$ close enough to $0$.

Therefore there is *no* $\varepsilon$ that has a matching $\delta$ -- and uniform continuity requires that *every* $\varepsilon>0$ must have one.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason 1:** $x_n= \frac {1}{n}$ is cauchy while $f(x_n)=n$ is not Cauchy.

**Reason 2:** lim$_{x \to 0^+} \frac {1}{x}$  does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take 
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n},\,y_n=\frac{1}{2n}.
$$
Then
$$
x_n-y_n\to 0\quad\text{while}\quad f(y_n)-f(x_n)=n\to\infty.
$$

Note. Suppose $f : A\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous. In such case, whenever $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}\subset A$ and $x_n-y_n\to 0$, then $f(x_n)-f(y_n)\to 0$ as well.